# Did I calculate $\text{Res}(\frac z {\sin z}, n\pi)$ correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've found that:

$$\text{Res}(\frac z {\sin z}, n\pi) = -n\pi,\quad n\in\mathbb Z-\{0\}$$

First, $\sin$ is continuous and therefore $\sin z\to 0$ as $z\to n\pi$, so $\frac 1 {\sin z}$ is unbounded in a neighborhood of $n\pi$. But $z$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $n\pi$, so $\frac z {\sin z}$ is unbounded and thus the singularity at $n\pi$ is not removable.

On the other hand, the Taylor expansion of $\sin$ around $n\pi$ shows that $\sin z=(z-n\pi)g(z-n\pi)$, where $g$ is holomorphic around $n\pi$ and $g(0)\neq0$. So $(z-n\pi)\frac z {\sin z}=\frac z {g(z-n\pi)}$ is holomorphic near $n\pi$ and the singularity is a simple pole.

Therefore the Residue can be found as the limit of $(z-n\pi)\frac z {\sin z}$ as $z\to n\pi$. We have by the Taylor's expansion of $\sin$:

$$\sin z = \sin'(n\pi)(z-n\pi)+\ ... = -1(z - n\pi) +\ ...$$

So $(z-n\pi)\frac 1 {\sin z}\to -1$ and $(z-n\pi)\frac z {\sin z}\to -n\pi$.

Comment: You should re-evaluate $\cos (n\pi)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer $\sin'n\pi=\cos n\pi$ is $1$ if $n$ is odd and $-1$ if $n$ is even?

Comment: The other way round, it's $(-1)^n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I have a mnemonic for the trig derivatives that sometimes bites me in the rear when I forget you have to go clockwise rather than anticlockwise, so I thought $\sin'=-\cos$ for a second and forgot to edit the rest of the comment.

Comment: No, you go counterclockwise (unless your clock goes the same way as the one on Prague's old synagogue), and $\sin' = \cos$. But $\cos 0 = 1,\, \cos \pi = -1$.